# AutoSuggestBox restores Text after pressing Escape

Tags: win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

I'm using an AutoSuggestBox to perform Search. It works as expected except when I set the Text property programmatically.
As an example, let's assume the following xaml:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <AutoSuggestBox x:Name="SearchBox" />
        <Button Content="Clear" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

On the Click event handler, I've put:

```
SearchBox.Text = string.Empty;
SearchBox.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
```

As you can see, the goal here is to Clear the AutoSuggestBox text. After I click on the button the Text is cleared but, if I press Escape, the previous Text is restored.

Is there any way to override this escape behaviour?

Thanks.
DMVC

Comment: Workaround would  be handling Escape key. Use  Window.Current.CoreWindow.CharacterReceived to handle escape key(args.KeyCode == 27)

Comment: And what should I do in the AutoSuggestBox when I capture the Escape key?

Comment: I tried clearing text. But sadly it doesn't work too